# Internal Server Error in Partner communities when using extension controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

We have a appexchange app in which there is a global class.
We are using this global class as controller in  local VF page and also created a extension class. When i try to use the variable declared in my extension class in my VF page i get an error while viewing this page in communities.

This page is viewable when logged as a salesforce user.

This extension class is accessible in the profile of the community user. If i remove the reference to the variable in extension class from the VF page then the page is working fine.

```
 public with sharing class homePagectrl {
public transient List<Lead> MyLeads { get; set; }

public CMhomePage (xxx.xxx_DashboardHome_G controller) 
{
    MyLeads = [SELECT Company,Description,createdDate FROM Lead WHERE ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserID()];
}
}
```

I am using MyLeads list in a apex:datatable

```
<apex:dataTable var="cv" value="{!MyLeads}" styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-checks media-table dataTable" width="100%">
              <apex:column >
                                                <apex:facet name="header">Company</apex:facet>
                                                    <a href="/{!cv.id}" target="_blank">{!cv.Company}</a>
                                                </apex:column>
                                                <apex:column >
                                                    <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
                                                    <apex:outputText value="{!cv.description}" />
                                                </apex:column>
                                                <apex:column >
                                                    <apex:facet name="header">Created Date</apex:facet>
                                                    <apex:outputField/> value="{!cv.CreatedDate}" />
                                                </apex:column>


          </apex:dataTable>
```

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
>   https://xxxx-main-148c47f13c9.force.com/partners/apex/DashBoardHomePage_G?autoMapValues=1&inline=1&core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewServlet.getInlinedContentRequest=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://xxxx-main-148c47f13c9.force.com/partners/home/home.jsp&sdfcIFrameOrigin=https://xxxx-main-148c47f13c9.force.com/partners/home/home.jsp"

I can see this error in the console of firebug. This VF page is a  homepage component.

When i look at the debug logs

There are 2 logs generated

1. One with all the statements happening in the controller and the extension. The code in the extension is run. There is no exception there.
2. Second log has the following

> 16.0
>
> APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
>
> 16:47:12.088 (88052188)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>
> 16:47:12.088
>   (88105048)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|066j00000004cCJ|VF:
>   /apex/Exception
>
> 16:47:12.035 (108320555)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
>
> 16:47:12.035|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
>
> 16:47:12.108 (108378749)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/Exception
>
> 16:47:12.109 (109354061)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

I am not sure where the issue is ? Any pointers would be of great help

Comment: You're not querying Owner.Name in your extension but you are attempting to display it on the page. What happens if you remove this from the VF page, does it work?

Comment: Its still the same error. I had tested that out before. Sorry  i didnt update the code here

Comment: What Communities User licenses do you use? Partner Community or Customer Community? I think Leads are available to Partner Community License users. So if you use Customer community this can be the issue. Here is the link to Community User Licenses doc: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @PaulBoiko Its partner community, so that should not be an issue